# Error when trying to clone repositry using gcloud

Tags: gcloud

I'm trying to clone a repo from google cloud and I get this error
**ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the error. I was using this command
gcloud source repos clone [repo-name]--[project-Id]
But this command worked fine
gcloud source repos clone [repo-name] --project=[project-Id]
More details here [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you ran the command on the right directory. This is important as the command needs the proper directory where it would clone the directory.

You can do this by doing the following steps below:

1. Create a directory on the Cloud Shell. You can do this by running this command:

   $ sudo mkdir [directory_name]
2. Change into that directory. You can do this by running this command:

   $ cd [directory_name].
3. After this, you will be able to run the command below:

   $ gcloud source repos clone [repo_name]

Also, take a look at this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories).